# How do I MANUALLY set an Identity field in LINQ-To-SQL (IDENTITY INSERT)

Tags: linq-to-sql, insert, identity

I have a table that normally, upon insert, the auto-key will increment. But, there are some instances when we want to set the ID (as would easily be done with "IDENTITY INSERT" in SQL).

Is there a way to accomplish this with LINQ to SQL?

Thanks,

Comment: so did you find a solution? BTW. How come you accepted the answer which does not give you the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/566e9540-911e-48b4-ac31-f69c0ab9f7fb/

Last reply here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1208607.aspx

Comment: I've just come across this looking for how to do this in EF, not LINQ-to-SQL, but this (accepted) answer doesn't seem to help: both links explain how to use DB generated IDs, not temporarily override them as I (and the OP here) are trying to do. Or have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, I'd guess Timothy tried the code. Did you? Perhaps the IsDbGenerated does the trick to allow setting the identity manually. What does EF stand for (forgot) again?

Comment: It's Entity Framework, the other .NET ORM. I'll ask a new question about it - thanks.

Comment: @RalphWillgoss the first link has the exact OPPOSITE of the answer!

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak its been a while and I see your point. Maybe the OP considered the fact that you couldn't do this as easily as expected due to EF using attributes/config to store the behaviour and had to work around that

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak have you tried setting IsDbGenerated=false (following the examples from the links) and updating the id field you want?

Comment: @Eduardo no, I'm using LINQPad that generates the DataContext for you and I don't think you can manipulate it. Anyway what I did was I just removed the IDENTITY from the destination column and re-run LINQPad so that IsDbGenerated would be false indeed - workd perfecly as I had a simple case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make IDENTITY increment always OFF

Edit the Model

```
public class TableName
{

    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

...
}
```