# In wp7 How to specify sql type of a column in entity class Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7.1, local-database

I'm developing a wp7 app using VS 2010 express edition. I want to create a local database in my app so I write a entity class for a table. I'm just following this MSDN tutorial [How to: Create a Basic Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) I cant find answer for my question there. My assumption is Database is going to be created when app is running first time on phone

How can I specify

- a column as nvarchar(25) and
- another column as datetime in UTC format

I used DBType attribute property to set a column for identity peoperty, How can I set seed value ?

Comment: What have you tried for setting the column values? and what happened when you did? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951909/specify-identity-value-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answers for my questions.  DBType property of Column attribute can be used to set sql types for a column in code. This is my solution:

```
    private string _placeName;
    [Column(DbType="NVarChar(10) NOT NULL")]
    //[MaxLength(10), MinLength(5)]
    public string PlaceName
    {
        get
        {
            return _placeName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_placeName != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("PlaceName");
                _placeName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PlaceName");
            } 
        }

    }
```

(I tried MaxLength attribute of DataAnnotation namespace, but entityframework is not supported in phone app)

Like this we can use '***exact text that is used by T-SQL***' in DBType property.