# How do I increase a secondary ID (not the primary key) using linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to log measurement from a sensor to sql table named `MeasResult`.

This table has its ID as primary key and one other ID named `MeasID`. I need to increase this MeasID by 1 every measurement logging. Every measurement logging will add 50 rows to database and these last added rows should have same MeasID.

I tried following:

```
private void BtnSaveMeas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new LinqDataClassesDataContext())
    {            
        var measid = dataContext.MeasResults.Max(x => x.MeasId) + 1;

        string id = ""; string plane = ""; int pos = 0; int dist = 0; double apert = 0;

        id = comboBMouldID.SelectedText;
        plane = comboBSurface.SelectedText;
        pos = Convert.ToInt32(txtTravelPos.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < daGridMeas.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            dist = Convert.ToInt32(daGridMeas.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            apert = Convert.ToDouble(daGridMeas.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

            var st = new MeasResult()
            {
                st.MID = id,
                st.Plane = plane,
                st.Postn = pos,
                st.Distnc = dist,
                st.Apert = apert,
                st.MeasId = measid
            };

            dataContext.MeasResults.InsertOnSubmit(st);
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I took three measurements and logged them, but in the the database `MeasID` column is null for all of them. The default value for the `MeasID` column is `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I MANUALLY set an Identity field in LINQ-To-SQL (IDENTITY INSERT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507515/how-do-i-manually-set-an-identity-field-in-linq-to-sql-identity-insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

`var measid = dataContext.MeasResults.Select(a=>a.MeasId).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(p => p ?? 0) + 1;`

Comment: @TeoLaferla - reverted back as you said it was working :-p

Comment: `var measid = dataContext.MeasResults.Select(a => a.MeasId).Where(p => p != null).Max() + 1;` this is the one working and there is a warning `The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'`

Comment: that warning is basically telling you that you don't need `.Where(p => p != null)`... If you are using that flavour of the statement, it will probably not work when the table is empty.